# Cypher Query including something like "Except"

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Does anyone know how I can write a cypher query like 
"return the node, except the person at question also follows Mr.X or Ms.Y"
I've been trying for ages...  Don't seem to manage. :(

I don't mean "return all except Mr. X and Ms. Y", but return if the above query fits.

Something like the following does not work if A also follows other people.

START a=node(1) MATCH (a)-[:follows]->(b) WHERE b.name!="Mr.X" and b.name!="Ms.Y" RETURN a

Comment: Do you mean that you want to return all people who do not follow Mr. X and Ms. Y?

Comment: Yes. Although there is the difficulty that it could be that these people (Mr. X and Ms. Y) do not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try `<>` for comparison instead,

```
START a=node(1) MATCH (a)-[:follows]->(b) WHERE b.name<>"Mr.X" and b.name<>"Ms.Y" RETURN a
```

Comment: thanks for trying to help me, peter, but like this it did not work. 
does this return A if the compared parts fit or do not fit? 
because i would need the latter. 

and how is comparison different to "!="? 
does it work with [?:r]-relationships?

Comment: i reckon that is what you mean, right? @peter
MATCH (a)-[?:follows]->(b) WHERE b.name!<>"Mr.X" and b.name!<>"Ms.Y"

Comment: with 
"START a=node(1) WHERE not(a-[:follows]->b) and b<>"Mr.X" RETURN a" i get "unknown identifier 'b'"... but there must be a way to say "he doesn't follow anyone named Mr.X."